# Having trouble creating a working login form (fairly new to vb.net)

Tags: vb.net

Check out my code, I think everything is working fine it's simply the ButClick sub that is the problem.

```
Public Class Login

    Dim strUserAttepmt As String
    Dim strPassAttepmt As String
    Dim ReadUsername As String
    Dim ReadPassword As String
    Dim ReadIdentifier As String
    Dim TeacherLogins(2) As Details

    Structure Details
        Dim identifier As Char
        Dim username As String
        Dim password As String
    End Structure



    Sub LoadTeacherLogins(ByRef Logins() As Details)

        Dim tblLogins As String = "\\Sjcdom01\mstudent\LHeywood\documents\A2\Computing\Comp 4 - Smail\Project\Text Files\Official Teacher Logins.txt"
        Dim TextLine As String = ""
        Dim ArrayCounter As Integer = 2
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(tblLogins)

        'loop through text file and load all logins
        Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

            'read next line from file
            TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine

            'declare an array and use it to split line from file
            Dim TempArray() As String = Split(TextLine, ",")

            'transfer each array element into the appropriate part of the student structure
            Logins(ArrayCounter).identifier = TempArray(0)
            Logins(ArrayCounter).username = TempArray(1)
            Logins(ArrayCounter).password = TempArray(2)

            'empty string before reading next line
            TextLine = ""
            ArrayCounter = ArrayCounter + 1




        Loop

        ReadIdentifier = Logins(ArrayCounter).identifier
        ReadUsername = Logins(ArrayCounter).username
        ReadPassword = Logins(ArrayCounter).password

        LoadTeacherLogins(TeacherLogins)
    End Sub

    Private Sub InputUsername_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InputUsername.TextChanged
        strUserAttepmt = InputUsername.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub InputPassword_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InputPassword.TextChanged
        strPassAttepmt = InputPassword.Text
    End Sub
    Private Sub ButLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButLogin.Click

        Do


            If strUserAttepmt = ReadUsername And strPassAttepmt = ReadPassword Then
                Me.Hide()
                Homepage.Show()
            Else : MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username and Password combination")
            End If

        Loop Until ReadIdentifier = Nothing

        Me.Hide()
        Homepage.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm looking to verify whether the users input matches any of the lines in the corrisponding text file.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: What happens? What is intended to happen?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to see if strUserAttempt and strPassAttempt matches any of the login details in the corrosponding file. ( ReadUsername and ReadPassword

Answer (score 0):

You have more problems than you think.

> Loop Until ReadIdentifier = Nothing

You never alter the value of `ReadIdentifier` so it will either never be `Nothing` or, if it is already `Nothing`, then the `Homepage` will immediately show.

Based on the code we can see, `ReadIdentifier` value will always be set by the last line in your file. If you think you are searching every line of the file, you are not, you are only checking if the username and password matches the last file entry.

> Dim tblLogins As String = "\\Sjcdom01\mstudent\LHeywood\documents\A2\Computing\Comp 4 - Smail\Project\Text Files\Official Teacher Logins.txt"

If you program has access to this share, then the user does too. It is too easy for someone to simply open that file and see all the logins.

> LoadTeacherLogins(TeacherLogins)

Your are creating infinite recursion which should generate a stack overflow exception. You just pass `TeacherLogins`, which is never changed in the Sub, over and over.

To begin fixing these things, select all your code, then press `Delete` and Google for how to authenticate in WinForms.

Comment: Am I approaching this login the wrong way entirely?  I understand the security issue but at this moment in time I just want to get the system working as it is still the prototype.  Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It's never too early to layer your code. Here's an example:

The TeacherApp class is a form containing a UserName textbox, a Password textbox, and a Login Button.

The TeacherDataSource class does the actual lookup against the file (using a LINQ expression) into a Dictionary in case the file is large.

The TeacherInfo class is your data object.

By keeping things clean, your code will be easy to understand and maintain.

```
Public Class TeacherApp
    Private Teachers As New TeacherDataSource("\\Sjcdom01\mstudent\LHeywood\documents\A2\Computing\Comp 4 - Smail\Project\Text Files\Official Teacher Logins.txt")
    Private CurrentTeacher As TeacherInfo

    Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
        CurrentTeacher = Teachers.Lookup(UserName.Text, Password.Text)

        If CurrentTeacher IsNot Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome, " + CurrentTeacher.Name)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Account Not Found")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TeacherDataSource
    Private Accounts As Dictionary(Of String, TeacherInfo)

    Public Sub New(filePath As String)
        Accounts = (From record In IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                    Select Terms = record.Split(",")
                    Where Terms.Count = 3
                    Select New TeacherInfo With {.Identifier = Terms(0), .Name = Terms(1), .Password = Terms(2)}) _
                    .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Name)
    End Sub

    Public Function Lookup(name As String, password As String) As TeacherInfo
        Return If(Accounts.ContainsKey(name) AndAlso Accounts(name).Password = password, Accounts(name), Nothing)
    End Function 
End Class

Public Class TeacherInfo
    Public Property Identifier As Char
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Password As String
End Class
```